# DOM manipulation without JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When working on client-side DOM manipulation, we usually use JavaScript or jQuery. I am wondering if there is any other way to do this without JavaScript or JavaScript-based libraries?

Comment: type script.. more features than jscritpt.. :)

Comment: If you explain why, then you'd have better answers, they're all over the place because your question is too broad. Simplest answer, vbscript for IE up to IE 10. In Firefox, you can use JavaScript instead of EcmaScript (which is what we typically call JavaScript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other real cross-browser scripting language than Javascript.
JQuery is **NOT** a programming language, just a library that help abstracting the browser's differences in their javascript API.

Browser vendor at its time tried to propose alternatives that were not well received. The main reason being that replacing javascript with something else would need all browsers to support it, which is not going to happen anytime soon (or more likely, not going to happen at all).

- Internet explorer supported VBscript for ages (up to IE 10)
- A special Chrome version ("dartium") natively supports the Dart programming language.

Now, that does not mean that you need to code in javascript for client side interactivity.
You can always code in one language, and compile to javascript.

Just to name a few

- C/C++ can be compiled to Javascript with emscriptem
- Java can be compiled to JS with Google Web Toolkit
- Dart can also be compiled to javascript with bundled compiler
- Haxe can be compiled to either javascript, PHP, ActionScript, ... with bundled compiler.
- CoffeeScript, TypeScript, JSX are all meant to be compiled to javascript.
- There are more!

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.

It depends on "browser vendors" and which interpretors they implement into their product. They pretty-much all have the JS JIT compilers now.
Chrome has (had?) a dart interpreter.
Throughout history some vendors have tried to "replace" javascript with another scripting language. Due to the ubiquity of the web and it's widespread massive global usage, replacing something as fundamental as the use of javascript inside browsers has proven to always be a failure.
Even add-on languages have died with time. I think this was dart's (Google) case.

So, theoretically "yes", in practice: "no".

Answer (score 3):

The standard says:

> HTML does not rely on a specific scripting language, document authors must explicitly tell user agents the language of each script.

It even has example of vbScript:

```
<INPUT name="edit1" size="50">    
    <SCRIPT type="text/vbscript">
      Sub edit1_changed()
        If edit1.value = "abc" Then
          button1.enabled = True
        Else
          button1.enabled = False
        End If
      End Sub
    </SCRIPT>
```

and Tcl:

```
<INPUT name="edit1" size="50">
    <SCRIPT type="text/tcl">
      proc edit1_changed {} {
        if {[edit value] == abc} {
          button1 enable 1
        } else {
          button1 enable 0
        }
      }
      edit1 onChange edit1_changed
    </SCRIPT>
```

So it depends on browsers to adopt a specific scripting language (as the standard doesn't rely on a specific language), JS is prevalent in most browsers. VBScript for example, is only available on IE <= 10 (as pointed out by @Juan Mendes).

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2)

**Edit**: I just noticed that this is an old spec (HTML4.01), the 5.0 spec says something similar [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#scriptingLanguages).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the device, OS and browser you can access the DOM and manipulate it creating an add-on or component.

For example on IE was possible (not sure if is still safe to do it) an ActiveX component in C++ to access and manipulate the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

For manipulating DOM you need a scripting language like JS, VB etc. If you are asking about various scripting languages than JS is not the only language.